# check if a string is in datetime (mm-dd-yyyy) format in a data frame in python

Tags: python, datetime

I want to check if a string in a dataframe is in datetime format. So far i have tried the following code but it does not give the result i require

```
import dateutil
from dateutil import parser
dt = dateutil.parser.parse('04-13-1994')
print(dt)

output: 1994-04-13 00:00:00
```

I expect the result as,

```
x='04-13-1994' 
is_date(x)

output: True
```

Comment: What is `is_date()` though? You expected a certain function but it didn't seem like you tried anything to make the function work.  Please see [ask].

Answer (score 4):

Use strptime

```
import datetime

date_string = '04-23-2019'
try:
    date = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_string, '%m-%d-%Y')
except ValueError as err:
    print(err)
else:
    print(date.year)
    print(date.month)
    print(date.month)
```

Answer (score 2):

if you need to really check if it matches, use the following code

```
import re
r = re.compile('\d{1,2}/\d{2}/\d{4}')
if r.match('x/x/xxxx') is not None:
   print 'matches'
```

else, you can just use a try catch

```
import dateutil
from dateutil import parser

try:
    dt = dateutil.parser.parse('04-13-1994')
    print(dt)
except:
    print('doesn´t matches')
```

Comment: the regex matches any three string on any length 0 or more times separated by '/' . You might want \d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4} -- though that might not be a valid date -- hence strptime.

Comment: oh thanks, suggest an edit and i will accept @fiacre

Comment: Don't use a blanket `except:`; *catch specific exceptions*. You don't want to catch memory errors or keyboard interrupts or the system exit exception here.

Comment: Also, `dateutil.parser.parse()` accepts a *wide range* of date formats. The question title seems to suggest the OP only wants to accept one specific format.